# simulate key press CTRL+V in firemonkey application

Tags: firemonkey

how can simulate the event key press like CTRL+V and Enter in an application Firemonkey Delphi for Mobile? 
The function like Keybd_event() but this function is only for VCL Application

Thanks

yes I have to simulate paste clipboard action to send in an other application on android.

Comment: What platform are you developing for? keybd_event can still be used in Firemonkey for Windows, for mobile platforms this event does not make sense since there is no physical keyboard.

Comment: Are you wanting to do this to simulate a clipboard paste action? Because in that case you can check for and use the clipboard interface.

Comment: yes I have to simulate paste clipboard action to send in an other application on android.